# filter array based on nested array swift

Tags: swift

I have an array that contains another array. I need to filter parent array with a value in the child array. I am actually confused on how to go about it and if it is possible

```
struct ConnectionDetailSection {
        var connections: [ConnectionDetail]
        let type: ConnectionType
        let itemsType: [ConnectionDetailSectionContentType]
        let itemsIndex: [IndexPath]         // permission's table view indexpath
    }

struct ConnectionDetail {
        var dsAccountId:  String?
    }
```

I want to filter [ConnectionDetailSection] based on dsAccountId. is this possible?

Comment: Can you post an example with values? Like Input and required Output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not properly clear to me, so please update your question with input and required output which may lead to change in my answer.

The answer is yes, it is possible to filter data in a nested array.

Just for simplicity, I have removed all the extra keys in the structure.

```
struct ConnectionDetailSection {
   var connections: [ConnectionDetail]
}

struct ConnectionDetail {
  var dsAccountId:  String
}

let detail: [ConnectionDetailSection] = [
    .init(connections: [.init(dsAccountId: "stack"), .init(dsAccountId: "queue"), .init(dsAccountId: "array"), .init(dsAccountId: "tree")]),
    .init(connections: [.init(dsAccountId: "sorting"), .init(dsAccountId: "searching"), .init(dsAccountId: "bfs"), .init(dsAccountId: "dfs")]),
]

let filteredData = detail.filter({ data in
    return data.connections.contains(where: { $0.dsAccountId == "bfs" })
})

print(filteredData) //[[.init(dsAccountId: "sorting"), .init(dsAccountId: "searching"), .init(dsAccountId: "bfs"), .init(dsAccountId: "dfs")]]
```

Now, let's say if we have an `array` => `ConnectionDetailSection`. In this array, there are nested arrays, in this example we have `data structures` and `algorithms`. So, if we want to filter out the `array` => `ConnectionDetailSection`, on the basis of algorithm like `bfs`, then we will just filter out the `array` on the basis of it's nested array and check if contains that matching `dsAccountId` or not, in our case the required `dsAccountId` is `bfs`.

So, it will return the filtered array and this is how you can filter the nested array.